# Do we ever meet Jayne's mom?

Tags: firefly

Having only ever seen the original TV series and the movie, I'm left wondering a lot about the Verse of Firefly/Serenity.

Namely, about the awesome woman who made Jayne his hat.

Do we ever get to meet Jayne's mom in the comics, or any other extended canon?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, we've not yet *seen* Jayne's mother in any of the extended material. There's a mention of her in "[The Message](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Message_%28Firefly%29)" when we see the awesome hat that she's made Jayne.

> **JAYNE :** *Haw haw. It's from my mother..."My dear boy. I hope you are well and that you get this soon in your travels." Travels..."Thank
>   you for the credits you forwarded, they have helped as Matty is still
>   sick with the Damp-lung. I made you the enclosed" --Ooh! Enclosed!*
>   He reaches in and pulls out a woolly knitted hat with earflaps and a
>   pom pom. He is clearly moved. He puts it on, continues reading.
>   *"enclosed to keep you warm in your travels. Hope to hear from you soon, love, your mother."*
>
> He closes the letter, proudly adjusting his hat.

[image: Jayne Hat]

There's also a further mention in the comic "[Serenity : Better Days](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serenity:_Better_Days) : Part 2" where we learn (in Jayne's fantasy story) that her name is Radiant Cobb.

[image: Light Page 1]

[image: Light Page 2]

Comment: I sincerely hope Wash made good on his namesa-wait, Wash?!  Holy crap.  I thought all the Firefly comics took place after Serenity...man I've got to read some of those.

Comment: @Zibbobz - That was from a flashback IIRC

Comment: @Zibbobz - Serenity Better days is a three-shot that sits between Firefly and Serenity.

Comment: @SystemDown - Each of the crew tell stories about their plans for the future. Jayne plans to be the captain of a ship called the "Radiant Cobb"

Comment: @Richard - Ah true. Need to reread my Firefly books anyway. Thanks!